# How to sum when they have same color with sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

[image]

i want to ignore productNo and sum all product count accordingly.

```
select sum(count), max(productNo) 
from Table 
where date between 117 and 118 
group by product
```

this one gives wrong result...

I want to have sum of counts for each Product-ProductNo combination

Comment: Your question doesn't explain why your query contains max(productNo)

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: MySql, sure i will tag now

Comment: because i want to get only one product no per date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select sum(count), max(productNo) 
from Table 
where date between 117 and 118 
group by product, productNo
```

with this it works :)

Comment: Please explain why and how it works so that people with less knowledge can understand and *re-use* this code sample :-)

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
 select product,productno,sum(count) as result
 from table_name
 where productno='X1'
 group by product,productno
```

Answer (score 0):

seems you need the firts rows  order by result

```
select product,productno,sum(count) as result
from table
group by product,productno
order by result 
limit 1
```

Comment: I just want to get one productNo count per day for a spesific product, it does not matter which product no.

Comment: update  your question add  your actual query  .. your actual  result  (a coherent data sample) and the expected  result  ..  as text data   (not image)

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't tagged any *DBMS* so, i would use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select product, productno, sum(count) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by product order by sum(count) desc) as seq
      from table t
      group by product, productno
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

You can also use `LIMIT` clause (but not for each product) :

```
select product, productno, sum(count) as cnt
from table t
group by product, productno
order by cnt desc
limit 1;
```

Some other DBMS requires `TOP` clause instead of `LIMIT` clause so, you can change accordingly but the idea would be same.